# ‘wp_site_health_scheduled_check’ Causes Failure Of Other Scripts

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I introduced a heartbeat monitoring system on all my websites late last year. The system involves using a `wp-cron` action to send a GET request to an API hosted by Better Uptime, triggered by `crontab` command (`wp cron event run --due-now;`) every thirty minutes. This works flawlessly on all my websites, except **one** where **every week at exactly 20:30 GMT** the heartbeat fails. I have been investigating this.

You can see the pattern for yourself here: https://status.paragondrones.co.uk  (*open the ‘heartbeat’ section*).

Firstly, I checked with Better Uptime. They confirmed that they never received the relevant heartbeats.

Secondly, I checked the `wp-cron` action timing (*a known issue*). That was fine.

Thirdly, I checked whether the Termly plugin was the cause (*another known problem*). It wasn't.

Turning my focus then to Wordpress, and after some lengthy troubleshooting, I discovered that:

- In 60% of cases, there was no `crontab` log. Probably because Wordpress was too busy to process the `crontab` command.
- In 40% of cases, a `crontab` log existed but the heartbeat action was missing from it. Probably because Wordpress was too busy processing scripts because …
- In **100%** of cases, the `wp-cron` action `wp_site_health_scheduled_check` preceded the failure.

*Note: the `wp_site_health_scheduled_check` action is a standard feature of Wordpress since v5.2.0, one of only two `wp-cron` actions scheduled to run once per week.*

My initial thoughts were that the `wp_site_health_scheduled_check` script was timing out or trying to utilise too many server resources e.g. RAM, but comparing PHP Variables across three of my websites resulted in no discrepancies – all values were identical. Specifically, `max_execution_time`, and `max_input_time` were the same and set to a relatively generous 120 seconds, and `memory_limit` was set to a generous 768M.

Of course, I could just disable the `wp_site_health_scheduled_check` action, but this only fixes the issue, not the underlying problem.

I am at a loss now as to what to do or try next.

1. I could try disabling the action, just to prove that it is the root
   cause, but that doesn’t fix anything.
2. Is there a way to log what `wp_site_health_scheduled_check` is
   doing, find out how long it is taking to execute?
3. Should I just arbitrarily increase the PHP limits to see whether
   that helps?
4. SiteGround, my hosting provider, has two ‘configurations’ of PHP,
   either ‘Standard’ or ‘Ultra Fast’. I’m not sure what the differences
   are but is it worthwhile downgrading to ‘Standard’ to see what
   happens?

This is beyond my knowledge. Any advice/guidance would be warmly received.

David.

Answer (score 0):

First, turn on `WP_DEBUG` to get a log of the issue. In your wp-config.php you can add something like:

```php
define('WP_DEBUG', true); //record all the errors
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG',__DIR__.'/wp-content/.wp-debug.log'); //you may want to move this to a more secure location (outside of the web root)
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); //don't show errors on the front end
```

Second, depending on your server setup, the `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` settings may not match what is used by apache/litespeed/nginx/etc when you use the command line. From the command line, try running `php -i | grep "max_execution_time"` and `php -i | grep "memory_limit"` to see what those get set to.

Third, I've noticed that `wp_site_health_scheduled_check` occasionally takes FOREVER to complete (3 to >60 seconds depending on the day). I suspect you are hitting the `max_execution_time`.

Best of luck!